# Difference between two Browser Panels in QGIS

Tags: qgis

What is the difference between "Browser Panel" and "Browser (2) Panel" in "View > Panels" menu and in right clik menu?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please, read the manual: https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/opening_data.html#the-browser-panel. And ask about something there that you don't understand.

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca Make a proper answer instead of commenting. This is the answer.

Comment: @etrimaille, from https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic : _"please make an initial effort to research the answer before you ask a question"_. I think it is not the idea of this site to rewrite the manuals in the form of questions and answers.

Comment: I think that It's usual. There are many answers/solutions that can be found in documentation/manual, however, they exist in GIS SE. One can miss the prase that can be the answer of his/her question and he/she can prefer to find the answer easily here.

Comment: @KübraNur, Hi. I think that is not necessary to delete the question. Also, Kadir has improved the answer including a way to customize the panels menu. I has voted to close the question and must be in the review queue submitted to the community vote. Do not worry if the question closes, it will not be deleted. Delete a question is used only in vandalism cases. What you can do is accept the answer (the green check).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please review the documentation about [the Browser Panel](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/opening_data.html#the-browser-panel).

The documentation says:

> You can import files into databases or copy tables from one
> schema/database to another one with a simple drag-and-drop. **There is a
> second browser panel available to avoid long scrolling while dragging**.

It is like opening two file browsers when copying files to make copying easier.

**Note**: In QGIS 3, If you don't need it you can remove "Browser (2) Panel" option by unchecking `Browser2` in `Settings > Interface Customization...`.

[image]